# iOS: CocoaPods issue with Google Analytics and AdMob

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, admob, cocoapods

Assuming:

- I have configured CocoaPods for **Google Analytics**, using `pod 'Google/Analytics`, following the
  official installation guide:
  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift
- I have configured CocoaPods for **AdMob**, using `pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'`, following the
  official installation guide:
  https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#streamlined_using_cocoapods
- I generated the `GoogleService-Info.plist` configuration file, specifying both Analytics and AdMob services, using the button reported here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift#get-config

When I start the app I get the warning:

> You have enabled the AdMob service in Developer Console, but it
>   appears as though your Podfile is missing the line: 'pod
>   "Google/AdMob" or you may need to run `pod update` in your project
>   directory.

Then the app crashes with the error:

> assertion failed: Error configuring Google services: Optional(Error
>   Domain=com.google.greenhouse Code=-106 "Missing expected subspecs."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Some subspecs are not pod
>   installed. See log for details., NSLocalizedDescription=Missing
>   expected subspecs.}): file /myapp/AppDelegate.swift

which is thrown by the assert line, of this code the Google Analytics documentation said to add in the `AppDelegate.swift` file:

```
// Configure tracker from GoogleService-Info.plist.
var configureError:NSError?
GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)
assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")
```

I tried to I replace

`pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'` with `pod 'Google/AdMob'`

The app doesn't crash anymore, but I get the warning:

> You are currently using version 7.6.0 of the SDK. Please consider
>   updating your SDK to the most recent SDK version to get the latest
>   features and bug fixes

This is my full Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!  # needed when using Swift


target 'myProject' do

    pod 'Google/Analytics'
    pod 'GoogleIDFASupport'
    pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'

    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'

    pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.9.2'    

end
```

Comment: Happens if you import the Mobile Ads SDK by itself, too?

Comment: @Chauduyphanvu, it's a CocoaPod issue, so it has to do with the CocoaPod version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use the pod line with `Google/AdMob`, supported by the `GoogleService-Info.plist` configuration file, as it seems the most consistent way to manage multiple Google services.

The only problem is that it currently has a slower update cycle: the AdMob pod there is still at version 7.6 instead of the latest 7.7. However I still prefer that way. It should get updated pretty often anyway.

Answer (score 18):

Its easy to maintain using GoogleService-Info.plist file.

Just enable/disable services you want:

[image]

If you choosed you want to use some of them, then you need to specify them in your Podfile. Eg.

```
pod 'Google/CloudMessaging'
```

Full list of Google SDKs is available [here](https://developers.google.com/ios/guides/cocoapods).

Another way is to specify that you want to use Firebase. Just modufy your Podfile:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried to edit GoogleService-Info.plist and change "IS_ADS_ENABLED" to "NO"? If you are using "Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK" instead of "Google/AdMob" then your Ads should still work. "GoogleService-Info.plist" is not a requisite for AdMob (https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start#prerequisites).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue

Change

```
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0'
```

to

```
pod 'Google/AdMob'
```

Only problem is pod 'Google/AdMob' is one release behind (7.6)

Comment: What is the difference between `Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK` and `Google/AdMob`? Google AdMob documentation says to use the first one. Where is `Google/AdMob` mentioned?

Comment: not sure, if you use analytics it says use "pod 'Google/AdMob'" and "pod 'Google/Analytics'" but if I also use  Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK cocoapod complains "target has frameworks with conflicting names: GoogleMobileAds". It seems it is the same

Comment: I actually also use Analytics. Can you send me the link where it says to use "pod 'Google/AdMob'" and "pod 'Google/Analytics'"? thanks