# App Delegate crashes because of Firebase initialization

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I am getting this error that's causing the AppDelegate to crash

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.google.greenhouse', reason: 'Error Domain=com.google.greenhouse Code=-102 "Unable to correctly configure subspec Analytics" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=Tracking ID must not be nil or empty., NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to correctly configure subspec Analytics}'

I have followed the Firebase guide from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup)

What can be the reason? 
Also I don't intend to use google analytics as for now. Any fix?

**EDIT:**

[image: Location of GoogleService-Info.plist]

**Note: I have removed the IDs and the Keys for this screenshot**
[image: GoogleService-Info.plist content]

Comment: your googleinfo plist is probably not at correct location or nil

Comment: Where should the GoogleInfo.plist be loacted? @Shubhank

Comment: where is it in your project. post the screenshot of its location. It should be where the .xcode project is

Comment: It is inside Supporting Files along with Info.Plist @Shubhank

Comment: @DarthVader have you get solution to this issue? I am facing same issue. please help me if you got any solution.

Comment: @nilam_mande I am still working on it. If I get a solution I will post it.

Comment: I have a minimal working firebase analytics implementation.  You do NOT have to put the GoogleService-Info.plist next to the project file. I do not.  
  
I had to remove Google Analytics from my app/pods, though, as below.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I asked the Firebase team on this issue and they have responded.

> Things you can check if the issue still persist.
>   Check to see that the GoogleService-Info.plist file is at the correct location i.e at the project root.
>   Check your IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED in the google plist. Try changing it.
>   Try removing pod 'Google/Analytics'.
>   Add  -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled to get more debugging information.

My problem was solved by removing Google/Analytics pod.

Comment: My problem was solved by removing Google/Analytics pod. (Y)

Answer (score 112):

The accepted solution was to remove Google Analytics.
But you actually can have both Firebase and Google Analytics.
The solution I found was to add TRACKING_ID into GoogleService-Info.plist

for example, add this:

```
<dict>
    <key>TRACKING_ID</key>
    <string>UA-XXXXXX-X</string>
```

Comment: from where i can get the value of tracking iD?

Comment: I'm glad this helps.
@jayantrawat you should get this from google analytics

Comment: I think GA stopped allowing the use of mobile app tracking in GA. Today I tried and could not get a tracking ID. The only option was to use Firebase.

Comment: Well, ideally it should be accepted answer. To get tracking id open your google analytics and go to select your project ->Admin->Tracking Info->Tracking Code->Tracking ID

Answer (score 10):

We had the exact same error and solved by removing

```
pod 'Google/Analytics'
```

from Podfile.

In our case, we had been using GA and switch to Firebase + TagManager Solution, but just forgot to remove 'Google/Analytics' from Podfile.
(Even we remove 'Google/Analytics', TagManager installs GoogleAnalytics for dependencies but errors are gone. Curious but it works...)

Answer (score 4):

If would like to have both Google Analytics and Firebase. Please add two lines of code in GoogleService-Info file. Hope it will help

```
 <key>TRACKING_ID</key>
<string>UA-123456789-0</string>
```

Answer (score 3):

Enable/Disable Services That You Want in my Case i only need Analytics so i set YES in IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED and Other services set to NO.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38684971/4125508)

Answer (score 3):

Delete From Podfile -->  pod 'Google/Analytics'

Answer (score 1):

If it was not the location of your googleservice-info.plist file. Check your IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED in the google plist. Maybe try changing it to the opposite of what it currently is. 
Also, you can add this launch option to get more debug info. Maybe it will help. 
Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme -> Arguments passed on launch:

```
-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions suggested here worked for me. The only thing that did was disabling Firebase Analytics, by adding "FIREBASE_ANALYTICS_COLLECTION_ENABLED" (Boolean) to GoogleService-Info.plist and setting it to "NO" (taken from: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/disable-analytics)

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the **GoogleService-Info.plist** file is at the correct location i.e at the project root.

I have added a screenshot of my project for you to check for reference.

[image]

Comment: can you show your location of plist and the plist content by updating the question

Comment: Check it out @Shubhank

Comment: from the error it seems to be crashing cause of analytics being enabled for your app. can you try setting it to NO in plist - clean app and re run to check if it works

Comment: IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED is set to NO in my app.

Comment: okay, can you also check if the plist is actually added to the current target ? it might just not be in the copy resources section and not being bundled to the app during compile.

Comment: I just checked it. It is there in the Copy Build Resources

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113982/discussion-between-shubhank-and-darth-vader).