# Error Sigabrt with Google Sign In Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, google-signin, sigabrt

I am experiencing an error on build in the AppDelegate file which is a sigabrt error. I have already read many other threads on sigabrt, but I am asking how to fix this sigabrt error because of how it is related to the Google Sign In.

ViewController.swift code:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleSignIn
import Firebase
class ViewController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupGoogleButtons()
    }

    fileprivate func setupGoogleButtons(){
        //default google sign in button
        let googleButton = GIDSignInButton()
        googleButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 116 + 80, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 50)
        view.addSubview(googleButton)

        //custom google sign in button
        let customButton = UIButton(type: .system)
        customButton.frame = CGRect(x: 16, y: 116 + 80 + 66, width: view.frame.width - 32, height: 50)
        customButton.backgroundColor = .blue
        customButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        customButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)
        customButton.setTitle("Google Sign In #2", for: .normal)
        customButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleCustomGoogleSignIn), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(customButton)
    }

    func handleCustomGoogleSignIn() {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

AppDelegate file code:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        FIRApp.configure()

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FIRApp.defaultApp()?.options.clientID
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self

        return true
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if let err = error {
            print("Failed to log into Google: ", err)
            return
        }

        print("Successfully logged into Google", user)

        guard let idToken = user.authentication.idToken else { return }
        guard let accessToken = user.authentication.accessToken else { return }
        let credentials = FIRGoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: idToken, accessToken: accessToken)

        FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(with: credentials, completion: { (user, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print("Failed to create a Firebase User with Google account: ", err)
                return
            }

            guard let uid = user?.uid else { return }
            print("Successfully logged into Firebase with Google", uid)
        })
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url,
                                             sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
                                             annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
        return true
    }
}
```

Console Error message:

```
objc[12677]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Users/tarunaarora/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x119012998) and /Users/tarunaarora/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x118e34880). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2016-11-21 21:44:27.647 GunnOracleGoogleSignIn[12677:470666] Firebase automatic screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2016-11-21 21:44:27.929: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO
2016-11-21 21:44:27.928 GunnOracleGoogleSignIn[12677] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000001] Configuring the default app.
2016-11-21 21:44:28.330 GunnOracleGoogleSignIn[12677:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3501000 started
2016-11-21 21:44:28.542 GunnOracleGoogleSignIn[12677:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see (google url//can't show because it is goo.gl))
2016-11-21 21:44:28.637 GunnOracleGoogleSignIn[12677:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2016-11-21 21:44:28.782 GunnOracleGoogleSignIn[12677] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000019] Clearcut post completed.
2016-11-21 21:44:30.143 GunnOracleGoogleSignIn[12677:] <FIRAnalytics/WARNING> The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. Learn more at (Can't show goo.gl url)
2016-11-21 21:44:31.086 GunnOracleGoogleSignIn[12677:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
2016-11-21 21:44:31.841 GunnOracleGoogleSignIn[12677:470666] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'uiDelegate must either be a |UIViewController| or implement the |signIn:presentViewController:| and |signIn:dismissViewController:| methods from |GIDSignInUIDelegate|.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001076ffd4b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010716121e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001077692b5 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   GunnOracleGoogleSignIn              0x000000010619df7e -[GIDSignIn signInWithOptions:] + 88
    4   GunnOracleGoogleSignIn              0x00000001061a1c13 -[GIDSignInButton pressed] + 242
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010823845c -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
    6   UIKit                               0x00000001083be344 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    7   UIKit                               0x00000001083be65d -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 444
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001083bd559 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 668
    9   UIKit                               0x00000001082a5d5d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2747
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001082a744b -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4011
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010825454b -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 371
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000108a3fa0f __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 3248
    13  UIKit                               0x0000000108a38745 __handleEventQueue + 4879
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001076a48e1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107689b0c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107688ff6 __CFRunLoopRun + 918
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000107688a04 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    18  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010bad6a6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    19  UIKit                               0x0000000108236808 UIApplicationMain + 159
    20  GunnOracleGoogleSignIn              0x00000001060f669f main + 111
    21  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010a4a368d start + 1
    22  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Let me know if there is anything else that needs to be included.

Comment: Please read the error message carefully. The crucial information is `'uiDelegate must either be a |UIViewController| or implement the |signIn:presentViewController:| and |signIn:dismissViewController:| methods from |GIDSignInUIDelegate|.'`

Comment: @vadian so do you know how to fix this error because I do not fully understand it that well

Comment: Since `AppDelegate` is not a view controller you need to implement the suggested methods.

Comment: @vadian could you tell me how to implement these methods and which methods I should implement please

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google API. The methods are clearly mentioned in the error message. Type the first characters of `signIn` and use code completion.

Comment: @vadian I just recreated the same project, by copying the Assets and Storyboard. After doing this, I just went through the steps again, and it ended up working. I think, because I was trying to make a sign out button, that it may have interfered with what I was doing before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the reason was this error:

```
Unable to correctly configure subspec Analytics
```

which is fixed by setting a correct tracking id to `GoogleService-Info.plist`. See for more info: [App Delegate crashes because of Firebase initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37660953/app-delegate-crashes-because-of-firebase-initialization)